# nitro Error: stat no such file or directory

Tags: nitro

I've gone over the way to set up Nitro over and over again but I keep running into the same problem. I even destroyed nitro and deleted everything and restarted to see if I just did something wrong.

When I do "nitro create" I get the root to `/home/ubuntu/sites/projectname/project/web` but after mounting I get `"Error: stat /home/randomfolder/projectname: no such file or directory.`

I have tried to manually create those paths and run it all again and I still receive that same error. It adds to the nitro-dev.yaml file just fine and it says that it's mounting but I don't get anything beyond that and I can't open anything with the chosen hostnames.